# Hackerrank Inherited Code

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge, exception

I'm back at it again with an Hackerrank challenge-[Inherited Code](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/inherited-code/copy-from/32047130) . I just learnt exception and I thought it will be a great idea to get a second opinion on my implemented `BadLengthException` struct .

> You inherited a piece of code that performs username validation for
>   your company's website. The existing function works reasonably well,
>   but it throws an exception when the username is too short. Upon
>   review, you realize that nobody ever defined the exception.
>
> The inherited code is provided for you in the locked section of your
>   editor. Complete the code so that, when an exception is thrown, it
>   prints `Too short: N` (where \$N\$  is the length of the given
>   username).
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer, \$T\$ , the number of test cases. 
>   Each of the \$T\$ subsequent lines describes a test case as a single
>   username string, \$ U\$ .
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$ 1 \leq T \leq 1000\$
> - \$ 1 \leq |U| \leq 100\$
> - The username consists only of uppercase and lowercase letters.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> You are not responsible for directly printing anything to stdout. If
>   your code is correct, the locked stub code in your editor will print
>   either `Valid` (if the username is valid), `Invalid` (if the username
>   is invalid), or `Too short: N` (where \$N\$ is the length of the
>   too-short username) on a new line for each test case.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
> 3
> Peter
> Me
> Arxwwz
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
> Valid
> Too short: 2
> Invalid
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Username Me is too short because it only contains  characters, so your
>   exception prints `Too short: 2` .  All other validation is handled by
>   the locked code in your editor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

/* Define the exception here */
struct BadLengthException : public exception {
    int number;    
    public :
        BadLengthException(int n){
            number = n;            
        }

   const char * what () const throw () {
       std::stringstream ss;
       ss << number;
       return ss.str(). c_str();

   }
};

bool checkUsername(string username) {
    bool isValid = true;
    int n = username.length();
    if(n < 5) {
        throw BadLengthException(n);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if(username[i] == 'w' && username[i+1] == 'w') {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}

int main() {
    int T; cin >> T;
    while(T--) {
        string username;
        cin >> username;
        try {
            bool isValid = checkUsername(username);
            if(isValid) {
                cout << "Valid" << '\n';
            } else {
                cout << "Invalid" << '\n';
            }
        } catch (BadLengthException e) {
            cout << "Too short: " << e.what() << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Final Thoughts**

- I thought it was a great idea to used a `struct` as opposed `class` as a struct is for small grouping
- Just like the previous question, I have no access to change  the headers,  `main()` and `checkUsername()` so I couldn't remove the `using namespace std`

Comment: If the exception class was never defined, how did the code you supposedly inherited ever compile in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really aimed at the core of your code and is more a reflection of the code challenge you're solving.

`BadLengthException` isn't a great name for the exception being represented.  It doesn't tell the caller that the name was too short (the exception *could* be used to represent a length that was too long).  The exception as you've implemented it has no *why*, so the exception itself doesn't contain sufficient information to tell the caller that it was too short / too long.  With that in mind, I would have been tempted to actually implement a `TooShortException` and then create `typedef` so that the supplied code still worked:

```
typedef TooShortException BadLengthException;
```

Answer (score 2):

- structs are public by default

  So this does not really make sense

  ```
  struct BadLengthException : public exception {
      int number;
  public :
      ...
  };
  ```

  Either put the declaration of `number` below `public :` or remove `public :`
- `using namespace std`

  You may be forced to keep `using namespace std` but your interface does not.  I recommend changing

  ```
  struct BadLengthException : public exception {
  ```

  to

  ```
  struct BadLengthException : public std::exception {
  ```
- Prefer to use `class` here rather than a `struct`

  The most accepted rule I know for choosing `class` vs `struct` is whether the data members are private or not.  Since you have no reason to make `number` public, I would make the object a class.
- Use an initializer list for the constructor

  ```
  struct BadLengthException : public std::exception {
      int number;
  public :
      BadLengthException(int n) : number(n) {}
  ...
  }
  ```
- Use `noexcept` rather than `throw()`

  Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833241/difference-between-c03-throw-specifier-c11-noexcept).  Also note that `std::exception` member function [`what()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) is explicitly marked `noexcept`
- Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to format the number to a string
- Use [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) to ensure you are overriding a virtual function in the base class
- Undefined behavior

  You are returning a pointer to a temporary in `what()`.  If you were returning a reference in `what()` and the call site (code inside catch) specified storing a const reference you would be ok.  While you could provide another overload to `what()` that masks the inherited overload, you cannot change the code in `main`.

  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784262/does-a-const-reference-prolong-the-life-of-a-temporary) StackOverflow question and [this](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) GotW for related info.

  Essentially you have to store the string in the class and return a C pointer to it.

## Updated Code

```
class BadLengthException : public std::exception {
    std::string str;  // This is private since the object is now a class

public :
    BadLengthException(int number) : str (std::to_string (number)) {}

    const char * what () const noexcept override {
        return str.c_str();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe now is very late, but I think it is better if the username var is passed by reference. And the `username` should change to `user_name`.

```
bool checkUsername(const string& username) {
```

because pass by reference is faster, and to avoid modifying the username by an accident, should put const

Comment: Your answer would be better if explained `why` this changes would make the code better.

Comment: if the username var is very long,  you pass by values that mean the compiler makes a copy of it. Otherwise, pass by reference means the compiler did not copy it, so your program is faster, and to avoid modifying the username by an accident, should put const

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the explanation.

Comment: Also consider passing a `std::string_view` - that's more helpful with public interfaces, as it can avoid creation of a temporary string object from a null-terminated character array.